# Editar com modal e ajax não retorna os dados

Tags: php, ajax

No modal que estou a criar, insere, posso consultar a informação da tabela da base de dados, mas na parte de editar não retorna os dados no formulário que mostro ao utilizador, mas se colocar no `ajax console.log(data);`dentro do `success` retorna os dados do cliente que estou a tentar editar.

**ajax:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("Id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"./fetch",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){  
                     console.log(data);
                     $('#CodigoUtente').val(data.CodigoUtente);  
                     $('#Nome').val(data.Nome);  
                     $('#DataNasc').val(data.DataNasc);  
                     $('#Sexo').val(data.Sexo);  
                     $('#Estadocivil').val(data.Estadocivil); 
                     $('#Nacionalidade').val(data.Nacionalidade);  
                     $('#Responsavel').val(data.Responsavel);  
                     $('#Parentesco').val(data.Parentesco);  
                     $('#Contato').val(data.Contato);                    
                     $('#employee_id').val(data.Id);  
                     $('#insert').val("Atualizar");  
                     $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
                }  
           });  
      });
```

a página `fetch` com o php:

```
if(isset($_POST["employee_id"]))  
 {  
      $query = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.PsicUtentes WHERE Id = '".$_POST["employee_id"]."'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
      echo json_encode($row);  
 }
```

Como mostro na imagem que retorna os dados na consola:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Não estou a perceber onde está o problema.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center"><strong>Dados Utentes</strong></h3>  
                <br />         
<div align="right">  
<button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning">Novo Utente</button>  
</div>  
 <br />  
                     <div id="employee_table">  
                          <table class="table table-bordered">  
                               <tr> 
         <th width="25%">Código Utente</th>
                                    <th width="70%">Nome</th>
         <th width="30%">Valência</th>         
                                    <th width="15%">Editar</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">Ver</th>  
                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                               {  
                               ?>  
                               <tr>  
         <td><?php echo $row["CodigoUtente"]; ?></td> 
                                    <td><?php echo $row["Nome"]; ?></td>  
         <td><?php echo $row["ValenciasDescricao"]; ?></td> 
                                    <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Editar" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data" /></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="view" value="Ver" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               }  
                               ?>  
                          </table>  
                     </div>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  

 <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Dados Utentes</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div> 

<div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Dados Utente</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <form method="post" id="insert_form">  
                          <label>Código Utente</label>  
                          <input type="number" name="CodigoUtente" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Nome Utente</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="Nome" class="form-control"/>   
                          <br />  
        <label>Data Nascimento</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="DataNasc" class="form-control"/>   
                          <br />  
                          <label>Sexo</label>  
                          <select name="Sexo" class="form-control">  
                               <option value="M">Masculino</option>  
                               <option value="F">Feminino</option>  
                          </select>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Estado Civil</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="Estadocivil" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Nacionalidade</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="Nacionalidade" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
        <label>Responsavel</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="Responsavel" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
        <label>Parentesco</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="Parentesco" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />
        <label>Contato</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="Contato" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />
                          <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Registo" class="btn btn-success" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: Estranho, se você der console.log(data.CodigoUtente) retorna algo valido? outra duvida o $('#insert').val("Atualizar");   apareceu o value Atualizar?

Comment: @Lodi  em relação ao valor Atualizar aparece correto. Em relação ao console.log(data.CodigoUtente) retorna o codigo de utente correto

Comment: Posta o html da pagina também

Comment: @Lodi adicionei o html completo da página

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está salvando os dados em IDs, mas essas id não estão atribuidas nos input do html. Atribua as id corretamente aos input, ou use pelo name:

$('[name="CodigoUtente"]').val(data.CodigoUtente);